# Magento custom url rewrite

Tags: development

I would like to know how to make a custom url rewrite for my module.

ex. http://magento.localhost/retailer/stores/id/2
    to magento.localhost/retailer/stores/storename.html

http://magento.localhost/retailer/stores/id/3
    to magento.localhost/retailer/stores/storename2.html

```
  <events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <towersystems_retailer>
                <class>Towersystems_Retailer_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </towersystems_retailer>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

Controller Router

```
class Towersystems_Retailer_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {

public function initControllerRouters($observer){
    $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
    $front->addRouter('towersystems_retailer', $this);
    return $this;
}

public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
    Mage::log("match", null, "rewrite.txt");
    if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }

   $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    //split the urlKey by slash
    $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
    //check if there are at least 3 parts ('client', 'stores' and the actual store name)
    //if there are less than 3 it means it's not the url you are looking for
    if (count($parts) != 3) {
        return false;
    }
    //check if every part matches what it should
    if ($parts[0] == 'retailer' && $parts[1] == 'stores') {
        //get the store name - remove `.html` from the last part of the url
        $storeKey = str_replace('.html', '', $parts[2]);
        //TODO: add here additional check to see if $storeKey is valid (if an entity with your store name exists)
        //tell the request to map to your controller
        $request->setModuleName('retailer')
                ->setControllerName('stores')
                ->setActionName('index')
                ->setParam('id', '2');
        $request->setAlias(
            Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
            $urlKey
        );
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create a custom router in your module.
For this you will need this in the `config.xml` of your module inside the `global` tag

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <[vendor]_[module]>
                <class>[Vendor]_[Module]_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </[vendor]_[module]>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

Then create the file `app/code/local/[Vendor]/[Module]/Controller/Router.php`

```
<?php
class [Vendor]_[Module]_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract 
{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('[vendor]_[module]', $this);
        return $this;
    }    
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        //split the urlKey by slash
        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        //check if there are at least 3 parts ('client', 'stores' and the actual store name)
        //if there are less than 3 it means it's not the url you are looking for
        if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }
        //check if every part matches what it should
        if ($parts[0] == 'client' && $parts[1] == 'stores') {
            //get the store name - remove `.html` from the last part of the url
            $storeKey = str_replace('.html', '', $parts[2]);
            //TODO: add here additional check to see if $storeKey is valid (if an entity with your store name exists)
            //tell the request to map to your controller
            $request->setModuleName('module_front_key_here')
                    ->setControllerName('controller_name_here')
                    ->setActionName('action_name_here')
                    ->setParam('id', 'id of the store with the key $storeKey');
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually something like this but I get an error Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Comment: Use this to debug your router: http://tutorialmagento.com/fixing-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations

Comment: also when you said check for actual store name, $parts[2] is just the ID parameter

Comment: $parts[2] should be `storename.html`

Comment: I've added a snippet of my code above. I am trying to see if it would work I've hard coded the parameter for ID. I think I am not understanding something

Comment: Try replacing this `if (count($parts) < 3) {
            return false;
        }` from my code with this `if (count($parts) != 3) {
            return false;
        }`

Comment: now I get the 404 message. I am hoping just to make  progress wherein if am on http://magento2.localhost/retailer/stores/id/37 it will show in the url http://magento2.localhost/retailer/stores/custom_name.html and still load the same page.

Comment: I have updated my code for better understanding if I missed something

Comment: when I try to route this to cms/index/index it works. but when I try to route this in retailer/stores/index it doesn't work. but when I try it on the url it works properly. do I have to set a route or something on the $request?

Comment: Sorry. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: no worries your approach is perfect I just need to sort out why I can route to magento modules and not on my custom modules.

Answer (score 2):

**No code is needed** for that. Use default settings from admin

**Catalog->URL Rewrite Management->Create URL Rewrite: Custom**

1. Use "retailer/stores/id/2" as "Request Path"
2. Use "retailer/stores/storename.html" as "Target Path" &
3. set Redirect Yes & save.

Same for other one.

Comment: this is no good if you have 400++ stores